# await function returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, async-await

My goal is to "pause" the *EventListener* function in order to get something done by calling another function (*getCategoriesIDs*) that returns a value that I will use to continue the *EventListener* function execution.

When I log the *categoriesIDtoNameMapped* after the execution it comes out as UNDEFINED.

Would greatly appreciate your help.

```
form.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {

//do something

try {
    let categoriesIDtoNameMapped = await getCategoriesIDs()
    console.log(categoriesIDtoNameMapped)
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
            
//do something with the categoriesIDtoNameMapped

}

function getCategoriesIDs() {
    fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/categories', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${JWT_TOKEN}`
        }
    })
    .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((response) => {
        const categoriesIDtoNameMapped = {}
        for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            categoriesIDtoNameMapped[response.data[i].id] = response.data[i].attributes.name
        }
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            resolve(categoriesIDtoNameMapped)
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: `getCategoriesIDs` returns nothing. Did you mean `return fetch`? See also [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](/q/23803743/4642212).

Comment: I want to process the result from the fetch into an object categoriesIDtoNameMapped and send it back to the other function

Comment: @JoaoPereira so add `return`

Comment: Actually you just helped me solve it, I realized I have to return the object outside the .then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getCategoriesIDs needs to be an async function for you to await something on it.

To fix this you need make getCategoriesIDs as async function and use await for fetch

```
async function getCategoriesIDs() {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/categories', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${JWT_TOKEN}`
        }
    })
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
    }
    const responseJson = await response.json();
    const categoriesIDtoNameMapped = {}
        for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            categoriesIDtoNameMapped[responseJson.data[i].id] = response.data[i].attributes.name
        }
    return categoriesIDtoNameMapped;
}
```

Comment: Pretty much exactly that I was going to post :)

Comment: You don't need to do this, simple `return` would be enough

Comment: Ty for your help but I dont think this function needs to be async since the invoking function is already async and I call this function with await, so it will pause the execution to execute this function and then resume after. This is my understanding and it is working as intended. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @JoaoPereira You are wrong. This function needs to be async, as it uses `await` on `response`.

Comment: ^This is my understanding as well. Are you sure you are not getting {} as response  without async await @JoaoPereira

Comment: I can see that not making it async could make the fetch execute after the return, returning an empty object. But that is not the case in my code, it is working as intended. Why is that so? Is it because the fetch request is taking very little time since its locally? Im trying to wrap my head around the async nature of js

Comment: Thank you for your help! Still not understanding why my other solution below was also working, now I'm curious...

Comment: Maybe it's due to fetch taking very little time? Maybe try adding a timeout inside .then to confirm ?